# How to get the value of two nodes in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) as reference to do the following code. I try other combinations with no success. There is no security access to database.

So, How can this code read or get value of two nodes at the same time?

```
function gofb(d) {
  var r = d.getAttribute("data-id");
  var p1name, p2name, pa1, pa2, pb1, pb2;
  return firebase.database().ref('/wc2017/' + r + '/t1').once('value').then(
    function(snapshot) {
     pa1 = snapshot.val().pd1;
     pa2 = snapshot.val().pd2;
     p1name = pa1 + "|" + pa2;
  });

  return firebase.database().ref('/wc2017/' + r + '/t2').once('value').then(
    function(snapshot) {
     pb1 = snapshot.val().pd1;
     pb2 = snapshot.val().pd2;
     p2name = pb1 + "|" + pb2;
  });

  return firebase.database().ref('/wc2017/' + r).update({
   a0_start: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});

  console.log(t1name);
  console.log(t2name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the snapshot for the parent object's value. And get the values you want. Please refer to the following code.

```
firebase.database().ref('/wc2017/' + r).once('value',function(snapshot){

sValue = snapshot.val();
pa1t1 = sValue.t1.pd1;
pa2t1 = sValue.t1.pd2;

pb1t2 = sValue.t2.pd1;
pb2t2 = sValue.t2.pd2;

});
```